# Pass an array to web service SUDS (Jurko)

Tags: python, arrays, encoding, suds

I know I'm probably doing something pretty stupid or small (I hope) but what I'm doing is passing suds an array of data but all I'm getting is this error.

> suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:tankLevelDataArray. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 407. Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''. '.  Please see InnerException for more details.'

No matter what I try my program will keep getting this issue, this is my code that I am currently using to pass it the array.

```
def PosEncodedTankData( Id, encodedTankData ):
    global HOST2
    global PORT2
    global DATA

    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    #Setup Soap
    client = Client(HOST2)

    try:
        #Send data
        print (client)
        tankLevelDataArray = client.factory.create('tankLevelDataArray')

        tankLevelDataArray = np.array(sortData(DATA, 21, tankLevelDataArray))

        client.service.PostTankDataArray (1, tankLevelDataArray)
        print ("Message Recieved")


    except TimeoutError:
        print ("Message was not sent")
```

So when go through that method is just fails.. But I haven't been able to figure out what is happening.

I am passing a array of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind everyone, looks like the array needed was an array of TankLevelData and I was just giving it integers therefor causing my error. My bad.